# Access Pin Post of a group in apex using SOQL of ConnectApi?

Tags: chatter, lightning-community

I am trying to access pinned FeedItem on the group. I am unable to get from SOQL can anyone please give me a workaround.

Comment: Let me know if the answer on https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IYGb helps

Comment: I have copied the answer from the above link so that others facing the same issue might find this information helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IYGb) ,you can use the Connect Rest API to fetch the information of the pinned post. I was able to fetch this information with the below URI using workbench

```
/services/data/v50.0/chatter/feeds/record/0F97F000000F2ltSAC/pinned-feed-elements
```

Here,0F97F000000F2ltSAC is the group ID where the post was pinned in my org.

Incase you want to use ConnectApi Namespace, try using [getPinnedFeedElementsFromFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods)

> getPinnedFeedElementsFromFeed(communityId, feedType, subjectId)
> Get pinned feed elements from a group or topic feed.

Sample code snippet

```
public List<Id> getPinnedQuestionIdsByTopicId(String topicId){
List<Id> questionIds = new List<Id>();
ConnectApi.PinnedFeedElements pfe =
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getPinnedFeedElementsFromFeed(community.Id, ConnectApi.FeedType.Topics, topicId);
for(ConnectApi.FeedElement fe : pfe.elements){
questionIds.add(fe.Id);
}
i++;
return questionIds;
}
```